# Is there a helper method to parse an appSettings-like xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

By appSettings-like I mean like this,

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="myValue" />
</appsettings>
```

The result is a key-value collection that I can access like:

```
string v = config["myKey"];
```

but it is not necessarily located in app.config, so what I have is a string or a XmlNode.

[NameValueFileSectionHandler.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.namevaluefilesectionhandler.create.aspx) method apparently can do the job, but the input needs two objects, Object parent, Object configContext, in addition to a xml node, and I don't know what to pass to them.

Comment: To clarify you mean xml that is similar to the app.config file but not the same?

Comment: the format is the same. The difference is that it's not in app.config (or MyProgram.exe.config)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parse a string to a dictionary like this,

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<appSettings><add key=\"myKey\" value=\"myValue\" /></appSettings>");
var dic = xml.Descendants("add").ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("key").Value, x => x.Attribute("value").Value);
```

You can get the values like this,

```
var item = dic["myKey"];
```

You can also modify the values in the dictionary like this,

```
dic["myKey"] = "new val";
```

And you can convert the modified dictionary back to a XElement using this code,

```
var newXml = new XElement("appSettings", dic.Select(d => new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", d.Key), new XAttribute("value", d.Value))));
```

Comment: Impressive! just curious, how can I get the element back?

Comment: what element? if you talking about value of key it is in example `var item = dic["myKey"];`

Comment: I mean, you parse the XElement to the dictionary in a one liner. Is the reverse can be done in one line too? I can only think of a for loop

Comment: Great. I edited your code to add descriptions, I hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
Hashtable htResource = new Hashtable();
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(XmlString);
    foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectSingleNode("appSettings"))
    {
        if ((node.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment) && !htResource.Contains(node.Attributes["name"].Value))
            {
                htResource[node.Attributes["name"].Value] = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
            }
    }
```

Then you can access the values using:

```
string myValue = htResource["SettingName"].ToString();
```

Hope that helps,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really a "helper", but the framework includes something branded the **Configuration API**.  This works inside configuration files and will translate your configuration XML into classes.  Take a look in more detail here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178688(v=VS.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

This is always the sample I use (because I can never remember the exact structure of it all):

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx#

There is also a designer available that integrates with VS:

http://csd.codeplex.com/

Googling "C# custom configuration sections" will also yield a lot of results for you.

Comment: just a clarification, I didn't mean a custom config format (like suggested in the haacked link). I want still the same format. The difference is that it's not in app.config and the input is only a string.

Comment: @Louis long and short of it, I don't think there is a helper available.  Instead, write the string out to a file and use the ConfigurationManager OpenMappedExe stuff or parse it manually.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this but I think the code below might give you what you want.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap(yourConfigFileLocation);
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
        var setting = configuration.AppSettings["settingName"];
```